# How can I automate my Kafka listener and DAGs in Airflow for a streaming pipeline?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow

I'm trying to build a Kafka listener using Airflow and create a new task for every message that the listener receives.

To give to you more details:

I will listen a kafka topic, I don't know how many messages and when those messages will come.
I will receive that message and I will create a task with some python transformation and ingestion on mongodb.

The listener will be always working. The task will start when the messages comes and finish after the listener process the message.

I´ve tried do something like this:

My code DAG 1:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

@dag(default_args=default_args, description='Streaming pipeline', start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)
def job_offer_matching():
    
    def trigger_downstream_dag(message_from_topic):
        downstream_dag_id = 'downstream_kafka_messages'
        print(f"encountered {message_from_topic} - executing external dag!")
        
        trigger_dag_run_op = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id="trigger_downstream_kafka_messages",
            trigger_dag_id=downstream_dag_id,
            conf={"message": message_from_topic},
            wait_for_completion=True
        )
        return trigger_dag_run_op
    
    @task
    def listen_kafka_topic():
        # Set up the Kafka consumer
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            'test-topic',  # Topic name
            bootstrap_servers='hide:9092',  # Kafka broker address
            security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
            sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
            sasl_plain_username='hide',
            sasl_plain_password='hide',
            group_id='my-group',  # Consumer group ID
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',  # Start from the earliest offset
            enable_auto_commit=True,  # Automatically commit offsets
            value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')  # Decode message value
        )
        
        # Retrieve the data sources from the collection
        for message in consumer:
            message_from_topic = message.value
            print(message_from_topic)
            trigger_downstream_dag(message_from_topic)
    
    listen_kafka_topic()
    

job_offer_matching()
```

Code DAG 2:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
}


@dag(default_args=default_args, description='Streaming pipeline Downstream', start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)
def downstream_kafka_messages():
    
    @task
    def message(dag_run=None):
        print(dag_run.conf.get("message"))

    message()

downstream_kafka_messages()
```

Problem: It is not triggering the dag.

Actually, I was trying to do something inside the same dag not in a separated one, but well, using this approach here is also not working since the the downstream_dag is not being called. Once the first dag runs and listen correct the message printing the result, it sayd that will execute the external dag but it never happens.

Do you have any solution in which way could I automatize this streaming pipeline?

Thanks and have an amazing day.

Comment: Manually creating a consumer instance is the incorrect approach to using Airflow with Kafka. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-kafka/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

May be that have sense:

```
User -> Django App: Script and Options Selection
Django app -> Airflow: Request to run a script
Airflow -> Virtual Machine: Script Execution Request
Virtual machine -> Script: Run script
Script -> Connect Airflow: Getting Access Details
Connect Airflow -> Script: Passing credentials
Script -> Kafka: Getting data from sources and storages
Kafka -> Script: Data transfer from sources and storages
Script -> Data Conversion
Script -> Kafka: Sending transformed data to other databases
Kafka -> Other DB: Passing Transformed Data
Script -> Connect Airflow: Save execution results
Connect Airflow -> Airflow: Task Completion Notification
Airflow -> Django App: Task Completion Notification
Django app -> User: Display results
```